# How to deduce order of two variables store/load with acq/rel order?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I am trying to learn about execution order involving atomic variables in C++, and I have the following code.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), I have the following reasoning:

1. C++ enforce 1->2 order when executing
   Because no load/store can be moved before an acquire-load within the same thread.
2. C++ enforce 3->4 order when executing
   The same reason as 1
3. C++ enforce 2->3 order when executing

   Because 2 is a release-store to y, and 3 is an acquire-load from y.
   So 2 should be visible to 3.
   Thus, 2 should be executed before 3, and 3 will read the result of 2's write.
4. C++ enforce 4->1 order when executing
   The same reason as 3

From reasoning 1/2/3, we can deduce a execution order of `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`, and it will break reasoning 4.
From reasoning 1/2/4, we can deduce a execution order of `3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2`, and it will break reasoning 3.

Seems there are conflicts here.

```
int main() {
    while(true) {
        std::atomic<int> x, y;
        x.store(10);
        y.store(20);
        auto f1 = [&]() {
            int r1 = x.load(std::memory_order_acquire); // 1
            y.store(r1, std::memory_order_release); // 2
        };
        auto f2 = [&]() {
            int r2 = y.load(std::memory_order_acquire); // 3
            x.store(r2, std::memory_order_release); // 4
        };
        std::thread t1(f1);
        std::thread t2(f2);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        printf("%d %d\n", x.load(), y.load());
    }
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

My reasoning about why 2 must happens before 3:

1. From preshing, y.store(rel) syncs-with y.load(acq).
2. Then according to cppreference, we can have y.store(rel) Inter-thread happens-before y.load(acq).
3. Then y.store(rel) happens-before y.load(acq).
4. So y.store(rel) must happens before y.load(acq)

Comment: There's just the trivial ordering 1 before 2, and 3 before 4. No idea why you think other ordering are enforced. The program can print `10 10`, `20 20`. Even `20 10` is a possible output, unlikely but theoretically possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 will "happen before" 2, and 3 will "happen before" 4. This part is correct.

However, for 3 to "synchronize with" (and "happen after") 2, it must successfully read the value written by 2.

If it doesn't read that value (because it ended up running before 2), then no synchronization happens, and no ordering is imposed on 4 relative to 1. In this case, 3 is said to be ["coherence-ordered before"](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#def:coherence-ordered_before) 2.

The same applies to 1 reading the value from 4.

Comment: Do you mean if a store of y happens before a load of y, it should be visible to this load. However, there is no guarantee that this store must happens before y?

Comment: @calvin Yep, more or less. I think of it the other way around: if the store ended up being visible to the load, then it happened before the load.

Comment: However, I have another reasoning which makes me confused. From [preshing](https://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/), y.store(rel) syncs-with y.load(acq). Then according to cppreference, we can have y.store(rel) Inter-thread happens-before y.load(acq). Then y.store(rel) happens-before y.load(acq). So it results in y.store(rel) must happens before y.load(acq). Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: OK, seem the trick here, is whether y.load(acq) uses the value of y.store(rel)... If it does not, then there are no order...

Comment: @calvin: I've now seen several people who got the same misconception from cppreference's sloppy wording, that could make it look like a release store magically causes some other acquire load to wait for it. I wish they would fix it.  The C++ standard itself has better wording: a release store synchronizes with an acquire load **that takes its value from the store**.  So indeed, only if the value loaded matches the value stored do you get to deduce a synchronizes-with relation.